# How do I detect with jQuery UI that I dragged outside the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript

This is my current code:

```
@row.draggable(
  handle: '.Drag',
  helper: (event) =>
    clone = @row.clone()
    $("td:gt(0)", clone).remove()
    return clone
  refreshPositions: true
  stop: (event) =>
    if event.pageX < 0
       #do something bc outside of window
       alert('dragged out of window');
)
```

The problem is that the if statement (in the `stop` callback) is only true if I dragged the item to the left of the window.

But let us say I drag it out on the right, top, or bottom?

Is there a solution that covers all of the cases?

---

In case you cannot read coffeescript, this is what my code translates to (more or less) in javascript:

```
var _this = this;

this.row.draggable({
  handle: '.Drag',
  helper: function(event) {
    var clone;
    clone = _this.row.clone();
    $("td:gt(0)", clone).remove();
    return clone;
  },
  refreshPositions: true,
  stop: function(event) {
    if (event.pageX < 0) {
      return alert('dragged out of window');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do similarly for top: `if event.pageY < 0`.

For bottom and right, you need to check pageX and pageY against the dimensions of the thing in question.  Since [pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.pageX) and [pageY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.pageY) report the position of the mouse relative to the top left of the document, and the way to get the document's width is through [`document.body.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth), you can put it all together this way:

```
if (event.pageX < 0 || event.pageX > document.body.clientWidth ||
    event.pageY < 0 || event.pageY > document.body.clientHeight) {
    alert('dragged out of window');
}
```

Comment: Looks good :-) I will try it out! (Also I updated your links to use the correct ones from MDN)